# Install php-fpm + php-mysql + MariaDB on Centos from repos

Tags: mysql, nginx, php-fpm, mariadb

I try to take CentOS 6.4 x64 and install nginx w/ php-fpm on it (and that's easy part, no problem at all), then add php-mysql package and MariaDB as a mysql drop-in replacement. And here I face the hang...

I've added epel, nginx and remi repos, add `priority=10` line to its .repo files, and now as I install MariaDB-server the dependency also brings me MariaDB's "common" package. Then, as I try to install php-mysql, I see

**file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of MariaDB-server-5.5.27-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql-libs-5.5.28-1.el6.remi.x86_64**

warnings. If I deinstall MariaDB server, I'm able to install mysql-libs and php-mysql, but it won't allow me to install MariaDB later.

Is there any way to escape that (infinite) loop? I believe the solution is simple but still can't see it.

**Please help to install php-fpm + php-mysql and MariaDB as DB server!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rpm -e --nodeps mysql-libs
yum install MariaDB-server
```

Comment: That's looks like solution but will it be able to upgrade (say, via yum)? I'm afraid the upgrade will stuck due to dependencies.

Comment: I haven't tested but I don't think it will cause a dependency issue. Give it a try.